# How do you make omega 4 choose a different layout depending on the screen size?

Tags: theming

I have read all the omega 4 unfinished Documentation but I still don't understand how the layouts are chosen for mobile and tablet versions. I know I can create layout files that define page.tpl.php and that those can have stylesheets scss and so also css.

But I don't understand how to tell omega 4 to use layout phone.tpl.php when I arrive at the breakpoint for mobile phone screen sizes.

How do I define the layout for a specific screen size?

Context only gives me pages, views and such, but nothing about the screen size. The thing is I don't even need a different layout, I need different css (layout would be better zhough). Do I have to add includes in the sassy to only use css? Is it then overkill to use omega 4? And how do I go about it if I really do need a layout? What Controls which layout is being used for which resolution? Or am I doing everything wrong here?

Comment: That's not how responsive design works, inside or outside of Drupal - the markup is the same across all devices, which means the same templates are used to build it every time. Your CSS media queries will alter widths, hide elements, remove floats, etc, depending on the current breakpoint. Everything happens on the _client side_ with responsive theming, so anything which involves PHP to make a decision, like choosing a template file, isn't part of it

Comment: Fair enough. Let's leave out the templates then. How does it choose which css to apply then? In omega 3 you had different css for different widths.

Comment: You include the breakpoints you want to use from the global variables like this: `@include breakpoint($desk, true)`, and put appropriate styles under those. A good example is in ohm/sass/layouts/hero/hero.layout.scss

Comment: Thank you that cleared it up. I thought that was not the way since you cannot import files into breakpoint definitions. But it seems you have to add the actual definitions in these parts.